# Highcharts not showing graph elements or xAxis

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, highcharts

Hi I am trying to setup a basic highchart, but have hit a problem which I have been struggling to resolve.

I am capturing a JSON object using AJAX, and trying to display it as a graph, but only the title label, yAxis label, and the series are displaying. The columns in my graph and strangely the xAxis (even though the syntax is similar to the yAxis) are displaying at all.

I have anyone may know how I can resolve this it would be greatly appreciated.

The  of my HTML page includes the following JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>e
```

The  of my HTML page includes the following HTML/JQuery:

```
<div id="chart1" style="width:800px; height:300px;"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function chData (jsonData) {
   $('#chart1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Test Chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Values'
        }
    },
    series: jsonData,
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'ChartData',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));    // added to check valid JSON recieved
        chData(jsonData);
    }
  });

 });

</script>
```

Also, my JSON object (which I have checked in a validator, and is returned by the url: 'ChartData') appears as:

```
def chartItems
 @tmp2 = ["{"\name"\:"\rainydays"\},{"\data"\:[8, 14, 12, 16, 13, 23, 15]}"]

logger.info(@tmp2)
  render json: @tmp2 
end
```

I went through the documentation as well on highcharts' website, and have tried integrating further code (such as the 'plotOptions' as found in this e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/ ) but despite trying numerous things to get it working, unfortunately nothing has worked for me.

If anyone may be able to assist, it would be very sincerely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your array is a string and not a javascript object.

```
[-->"<--{\"name\":\"rainydays\"},{\"data\":[8, 14, 12, 16, 13, 23, 15]}-->"<--]
```

I've highlighted the offending quotes with **-->"<--**.

Also you have extra brackets:

```
[{"name\":\"rainydays\"-->}<--,-->{<--\"data\":[8, 14, 12, 16, 13, 23, 15]}]
```

And finally, I'm not sure why your strings are escaped.  Your final data needs to look like this:

```
[{"name":"rainydays","data":[8, 14, 12, 16, 13, 23, 15]}]
```

I'm not a ruby guy, but I think you want this:

```
@tmp2 = [{:name=>"rainydays",:data=>[8, 14, 12, 16, 13, 23, 15]}]
```

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks a lot for pointing this out. However when I remove the two most outer double quotes, my chart which was partially displaying beforehand, disappears completely from the page. If you have any idea how I go about resolving this it would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, Just to clarify I have amended the original post as the array shown is converted into JSON by a Ruby on Rails method.

Comment: @NamingError, see edits, I missed the extra brackets in there too.  You should update with your question with the code that is generating your JSON, this is where your real problem lies.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks a lot for the reply. When I change the data to match the last snippet of code it crashes the weage entirely for me, and I get message from Ruby on Rails about the syntax. You are correct though with regards to the syntax provided, except that Ruby on Rails requires it in the format I have in the original post when using the 'render Json' method.

In the second block of code I have:
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
through which AJAX displays the data recieved...and it is captured at that stage in the syntax you provided.

Comment: @NamingError, what's the error?  Does it error on the line I give or when it converts to JSON?  It ain't much of a JSON converter if it can't convert a hash containing a string and a list...

Comment: The error points out several things with the syntax...it is just not the format that Ruby on Rails requires for render json. It does covert to your syntax, when it is captured at the AJAX stage though, as proven by the alert I have inserted to make sure, namely:
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
So it doesn't appear to me to be the json object which is the issue. Also, the chart does appear partially, which does not occur if the data pulled in by AJAX is not in the correct format.

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks a million Mark! This got it working! Thanks again for that...very greatly appreciated! Genius! :) 

(Just to clarify the last snippet of code you provided fixes the problem!) Thanks.